# Are there any other "omni-" paradoxes known similar to omnipotence?

Tags: theology, paradox

The paradox related to omnipotence is well known - in one of the many possible forms it asks whether an omnipotent being can create a stone that it cannot lift.

While there are many similar paradoxes based on self-reference (like whether the adjective "not-applicable-to-itself" applies to itself), I do not know any other paradoxes related to the aspect of omnipotence expressed by "omni". For example, I do not know whether omniscience or omnipresence leads to any paradoxes.

Does anybody here know any such paradoxes?

Comment: See [Omnipotence & omniscience](https://www3.nd.edu/~jspeaks/courses/2009-10/20229/LECTURES/15-omnipotence-omniscience-2.pdf); but IMO the example is quite debatable...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for that reference! It is shown there that one cannot use one particular reasoning to infer contradiction from omniscience. But can there be any other ways to infer that?

Comment: You can get paradoxes when you attempt to combine omni- abilities with other beliefs. For instance: omniscience + freewill. How is it that God knows your freewill decisions prior to you making them - presumably freely?

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams I am not sure this makes a paradox - an action does not require to be absolutely unpredictable to be freely executed.

Comment: The implication of complete omniscience of future actions is that those actions have been predetermined, and if predetermined how can they be freely elected?

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams There is no contradiction here. As long as their predeterminedness is not known by you, you choose them freely.

Comment: Cantor's theorem shows no such set of all truths known by omniscient God, but all truths likely form a proper class which is known by God. Indeed according to Fitch's famous [knowability paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch%27s_paradox_of_knowability), if all truths are knowable by any non-omniscient  being, "all truths" must not include any of the form "something is an unknown truth by said being"; thus there must be no unknown truths by said being, which sounds oxymoron. Ergo omniscience like emanation omnipresence is likely self-consistent logically...

Comment: Even for the obvious lift an unliftable stone case, God may work in some very mysterious ways beyond our imagination (Leibniz called such cases miracle). For example modern neuroscience shows human mind needs some time duration (say t) to make any logical judgement, thus if God fails to lift the said stone and subsequently lifts the said stone in much shorter time duration than t, then for us we didn't notice any phenomenon occurred while actually God fulfilled both cases already, thus Descartes' omnipotence may still make sense, we just don't have epistemic access for such cases...

Comment: @DoubleKnot While I subscribe readily to your first comment (and would accept an answer of that content), your second one I find questionable. Omnipotence is not about us perceiving it as such but about the fact independent of anybody's perception of it.

Comment: I heard that Mr. Bean is dead! 